# Update Statement not working

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-express

So I have a SQL express server database. I have an inventory file. I have one statement to insert new records, and another one to update count in all records. The first one works fine, however I can not get the count to update. I wrapped each of those statement in there own try, catch and it does not catch. I am pretty lost here.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\out\b.txt");
        //System.Console.WriteLine("Contents of writeLines2.txt =:");
        int i = 0;
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {



                string sellername, sku, date1, quantity1, date2, asin, date3, date4, FNSKU;
                char[] tabs = { '\t' };
                string[] words = line.Split(tabs);

                sku = words[0];
                FNSKU = words[1];
                asin = words[2];
                quantity1 = words[5];
                Console.WriteLine("\t" + line);
                inventoryBLL u = new inventoryBLL();
                try
                {
                    u.AddToDatabase(sku, DateTime.Now, Convert.ToInt16(0), DateTime.Now, 0, asin, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, FNSKU);

                }
                catch
                { }
                try
                {
                    u.UpdateDatabase(sku, quantity1);

                }
                catch
                { }

                foreach (string s in words)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine(s);
                }


            ++i;

        }

        // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
 }
```

Here is the bll

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using ConsoleApplication8.DataSet1TableAdapters;

 namespace ConsoleApplication8
 {
[System.ComponentModel.DataObject]
class inventoryBLL
{
    private AmazonSKUsTableAdapter _skuAdapter = null;
    protected AmazonSKUsTableAdapter Adatper
    {
        get
        {
            if (_skuAdapter == null)
                _skuAdapter = new AmazonSKUsTableAdapter();

            return _skuAdapter;
        }
    }

    [System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute
        (System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Insert, false)]
    public void AddToDatabase(string sku, DateTime date, int quantity, DateTime date1, int quantity1, string asin, DateTime date2, DateTime date3, string FNSKU)
    {
        Adatper.AddToDatabase("A1B7M9EQGNCLQA", sku, date, quantity, date1, quantity1, asin, date2, date3, FNSKU);

    }

            [System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute
        (System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Update, false)]
    public void UpdateDatabase(string sku, string quality)
    {
        Adatper.UpdateQuery(Convert.ToInt16(quality), sku);
    }
}

 }
```

Here is the query:

```
 UPDATE       AmazonSKUs
 SET                TotalQty = @TotalQty
 WHERE        (MerchantSKU = @Original_MerchantSKU);
```

Comment: Odds are good it's something in your code.  If you wanted us to tell you what it was in your code, you should post it so we can provide a more specific answer.

Comment: Does the update statement hang? Or does it complete without doing anything? Did you commit the insert?
What do the statements look like?

Comment: @Fatal I run the code and it seems to work. I check the db and nothing

Comment: When you connect with a tool to check the results then you probably use a different connection. When your DML from c# program does not commit then you do not see the new data, because of Isolation from ACID. Do you commit your transactions in your program?

Comment: @Joe Tyman: Now that you've posted code, I've changed it to a +1.

Comment: @Fatal can you clarify committing my my transactions?

Comment: I do not see where you commit/rollback your transactions. For more basic info use google with 'db transaction', 'commit rollback', 'sql server commit' ...

Comment: @Fatal I believe that would be handled by my dataset, no?

Comment: I know nothing about the question, but as a general guideline you can't expect people to reduce this big wodge of code to a minimal counterexample and test it for themselves. You'll need to filter the problem down to a smaller subset of the code and then ask about that.

Comment: @Oded @abatishchev @cHao @Cody Gray @Graviton How is this not a question? I have a problem. I have update based on the info requested. I have a non-working query. I have asked stack overflow why is it not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try putting some output statements in your catch blocks.  Odds are excellent that it's reporting the error; but without acting on the caught items, you're likely throwing away the issues it is reporting!

Comment: I put a break point at the catch block and nothing catches.